# Page jumps when typing in textfields

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using Phonegap + Jquery Mobile for a Web App. I have a simple registration form. However, when i type any character, the page jumps and flickers Wildly. How do i overcome this problem on Android?

i have tried most of the solutions provided at :

https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/251

http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html and other pages. None of the solutions worked for me.

Or Is it possible to call an android page only for registration? Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may be looking for the wrong sort of flicker - is the jumping something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233857/keyboard-showed-messed-up-elements-position or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529796/ios6-uiwebview-and-positionfixed/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to launch the Android code from your phonegap html page

```
MyWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "MyHandler");


public class MyJavaScriptInterface 
{

    Activity parentActivity;
    MyJavaScriptInterface(Activity activity){
             parentActivity = activity;
    }

    public void processData(String parameter){
        /* your processing logic */
               /* you can  launch your activity here. which contains registration form logic*/
    }

in your html page 





<a href="#" data-transition="slide" onClick="window.MyHandler.processData("+value_to_pase+")">
Change this with your page code (html Page)
```